# Probability question about left-handed US presidents.

Tags: probability, statistics

There have been 7 presidents since Gerald Ford (including Ford).  5 have been left-handed, 2 have been right handed.  While 90% of the population are right handed and 10% left handed.

Let's neglect how many elections they won / terms they served and how good they were (Carter and GWBush were the righties).  Can someone tell me the left-handed bias that has been showed by this trend.  I.e. how over-represented are southpaws for their percent of population?

Comment: There is some selection bias. The author may have chosen Ford to now by noting the near run of southpaws. It would be more persuasive if say all presidents since $1900$ had been the sample space.

Comment: And, perhaps even more 'incongruously', compared with all Presidents, an unusual proportion of the last seven appeared on TV.

Comment: Yes, I deliberately started with Ford because the 4 presidents before him were righty.  On the other hand I wonder how reliable those facts are from back when people were force to write right-handed even when they were lefty.  But then again it is the most recent trend and so may be the norm now.  Anyway neglecting that selection bias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to ignore (the crucial possibility of) selection bias. If we were to pick $n = 7$ Presidents *at random* and find $X = 5$ left-handed ones, then two ways come to mind (out of possibly many) to express the incongruity with 10% left handed in the population.

**(a) Population Mean vs. observed number.** Under random sampling we might model $X \sim Binom(7, .1).$ So the population mean is $\mu = E(X) = 7(.1) = 0.7,$ so we might expect to see 1 (or 0) left-handers. By contrast, the observed proportion is $\hat p = X/n = 5/7 = 0.7142,$
which estimates the population mean as $\hat \mu = 7(\hat p) = X = 5.$ Intuitively, this seems much greater than
"expected."

**(b) P-value.** Under the null hypothesis that $P(\text{Left-handed}) = p = .1$ and given the data that 5 of 7 are left-handed,
we have $P(X \ge 5|n=7, p=.1) = 0.00018$ which is much smaller than $0.05 = 5\%.$ So we might say that we strongly Reject $H_0: p = .1$ in favor of $H_a: p > .1$. (In R statistical software, the statement
`1 - pbinom(4, 7, .1)` returns `0.0001765`.)

Comment: So that final number 0.0001765 is the probability this would happen if there was left-handed bias?  So lefties are over-represented by a factor of 5665.7?

Comment: No, assuming no bias in the population and a sample of size 7, it's the probability of getting a result as extremely large as 5 or more lefthanders,